# mysql DECLARE WHILE outside stored procedure how?

Tags: mysql

I fairly new to mysql but have MS SQL experience.

Is it possible to **declare variables** and use **while** statement
outside **stored procedure**?

I only found examples where guys doing like this

```
1. procedure created
2. execute proc
3. drop proc
```

Suggest me the right way

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you cannot do it. You can use these statements only inside BEGIN...END clause.

So, it is possible in stored procedures/functions, triggers and events.

More information here - [MySQL Compound-Statement Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html).

Comment: This is... pretty much a deal breaker if you're trying to port a MS SQL app to mysql (for example).
 Out of interest then what's the right approach when you're writing a migration script and you need to SET a variable to the output of a query and then do something conditionally (e.g. if I have value 'foo' then insert value 'bar' and insert value 'pants') in another table?

Comment: To answer my own comment you can write `INSERT INTO Table1(ColA, ColB) SELECT ColC, ColD FROM Table2 WHERE ColE = 'foo';` then chain these queries.