# MYSQL declare varchar issues

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am getting an error while declaring a varchar in MySQL 5.0.77:

```
DECLARE city varchar(20);
```

The above line of code works fine in an Oracle database, but not in MySQL.
Can someone suggest a solution? I saw a similar question on this site, but could not find a suitable answer.

One more question: `%ROWTYPE` and `%TYPE` are these declarations there in MYSQL?

Comment: [DECLARE WHILE outside stored procedure how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954095/mysql-declare-while-outside-stored-procedure-how/12954385#12954385).

Answer (score 0):

Per [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) DECLARE works only at the start of a BEGIN...END block as in a stored program.

DECLARE city as VARCHAR(20); in mysql will be correct
  are you asking about `session variables` in mysql like this `SET @var := 1` then the answer is yes

Comment: Still getiing the same error 
Could you suggest the MYSQL version u are using.
Mine is 5.0.77

Comment: are using declare inside procedure?or out side?