# PostgreSQL loops outside functions. Is that possible?

Tags: t-sql, function, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I'm comparing PostgreSQL vs. SQLServer for migrating purposes. Now I'm evaluating T-SQL vs. PL/pgSQL, the thing is that in T-SQL you can use loops or declare variables, for example:

```sql
declare @counter int
set @counter = 0
while @counter < 10
begin
   set @counter = @counter + 1
   print 'The counter is ' + cast(@counter as char)
end
```

There is no need to put it inside a function or procedure. Can I do that in PostgreSQL?

Searching on the web I found a [negative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954095/mysql-declare-while-outside-stored-procedure-how) doing it in MySQL but I didn't find such answer for Postgres.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You **cannot** `DECLARE` (global) variables ([there *are* workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261927/939860)) nor loop with plain SQL - with the exception of [recursive CTEs as provided by @bma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341097/939860) (which is actually *iterating* over rows, not looping, strictly speaking).

**However**, there is the [**`DO`** statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) for such ad-hoc procedural code. Introduced with Postgres 9.0. It works like a one-time function, but does not take any parameters and does not return anything. You can [`RAISE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) notices et al, so your example would just work fine:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _counter int := 0;
BEGIN
   WHILE _counter < 10
   LOOP
      _counter := _counter + 1;
      RAISE NOTICE 'The counter is %', _counter;  -- coerced to text automatically
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

If not specified otherwise, the language in the body defaults to `plpgsql`. You can use [any registered procedural language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang.html) though, if you declare it (like: `LANGUAGE plpython`).

Postgres also offers [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to generate sets ad-hoc, which may obviate the need for looping in many cases. [Try a search here on SO for examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generate-series)

Also, you can use the `WHERE` clause in a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) in plain SQL to fork cases and emulate `IF .. THEN .. ELSE .. END` ...

Comment: It's worth reiterating more strongly that **if you can re-cast your problem in terms of sets rather than loops, do so** - that is, if you can build an SQL query that works on the results in one go, it is likely to perform much better than resorting to procedural code.

Answer (score 3):

You can recursively query result sets using WITH RECURSIVE, assuming you are on Postgresql 8.4+. Docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

This would allow you to loop your set and process the data in various ways.

Comment: Thank you so much bma. But can i use Declare keyword? because sometimes you need to insert for example, or depending on some contidition if the condition is true insert else if... update... else delete... am i clear? 
Best regards.

Comment: "Declare", no, but using the WITH clause, you are able to submit a value in one of the topmost clauses, and reference that multiple times in subsequent locations of the query (also known as "chaining"). For example, in the link I supplied, the "regional_sales" section is used as the source for the subsequent section (named "top_regions"). That illustrates the query chaining I mentioned. In Postgresql 9.2+, you can use WITH clauses (aka "Common Table Expressions" (CTE)) to do "upsert" statements (which you referred to as the "insert inf true, else update, else delete")