# How to test my ad-hoc SQL with parameters in Postgres query window

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameterized-query

In Microsoft SQL Server, to test something like this in the query window:

```
select * from Users where LastName = @lastname
```

I can add this before the command:

```
declare @lastname varchar(16)
set @lastname = 'Troy'
```

But in PostgreSQL, I cannot find a similar way to do so. It seems the only thing I can do is to replace the parameter name directly with its value. It gets hard when the ad-hoc query gets complicated and the same parameter gets used several times. Is there a way?

Comment: BTW: "Postgres query window"? You mean a pgAdmin query window?

Comment: I too was used to the workflow from MSSQL of copying a parameterized query into query runner, setting declarations above it, and hitting run. That way I don't mistakenly change the query semantics in the process of modifying it for testing. It's pretty disappointing that there is no way to do this in postgres. One must always change a parameterized query (at the very least, variable names or inserting casting) to test it and risk an invalid test result.

Comment: Workflow also exists in MySQL using `SET @var = 123`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql. I knew I had used it before MSSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I config postgres to log all the commands, and copy the command from the log file, so all the parameters are already replaced with the value, and test the command in the query window.

May not be the best approach, but it is easy and works for me

Answer (score 11):

Various options.

Provide parameters in a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to have "variables" in **pure SQL**:

```
WITH var(lastname) AS (SELECT 'Troy'::varchar(16))
SELECT *
FROM   users, var v
WHERE  lastname = v.lastname;
```

This works for *any* query.
Since the CTE `var` holds a ***single row*** it is safe to append it with a `CROSS JOIN` at the end of the FROM clause - actually the short form with appending it after a comma may be best because explicit join syntax binds before commas. The additional table alias `v` is optional to further shorten the syntax.

**OR** cheaper without CTE. BTW, why `varchar(16)`? Just use `text`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   users
JOIN  (SELECT 'Troy'::text) var(lastname) USING (lastname)
WHERE  lastname = var.lastname;
```

**Or** use a **temporary table** to play a similar role for *all* queries within the same session. Temp tables die with the end of the session.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE var AS
SELECT text 'Troy' AS lastname;

ANALYZE var;  -- temp tables are not covered by autovacuum

SELECT * FROM users JOIN var USING (lastname);
```

- [About temporary tables and `autovacuum`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/are-regular-vacuum-analyze-still-recommended-under-9-1/18694#18694)

**Or** you can use **`DO`** statements like @Houari supplied or like demonstrated here:

- [PostgreSQL loops outside functions. Is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340929/postgresql-loops-outside-functions-is-that-possible/18341502#18341502)

Note that you cannot return values from `DO` statements. (You can use `RAISE ...` though.) And you cannot use `SELECT` without target in plpgsql  - the default procedural language in a `DO` statement. Replace `SELECT` with [**`PERFORM`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) to throw away results.

**Or** you can use [**customized options**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html), which you can set in `postgresql.conf` to be visible ***globally***.

**Or** set in your session to be visible for the duration of the session and only **in the same session**:

```
SET my.lastname = 'Troy';
```

The variable name *must* include a dot. You are limited to `text` as data type this way, but any data type can be represented as `text` ...

You can use `current_setting('my.lastname')` as value expression. Cast if you need. For example: `current_setting('my.json_var')::json` ...

**Or** use `SET LOCAL` for the effect to only last for the current ***transaction***. See:

- [Passing user id to PostgreSQL triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers)

**Or** you can use tiny **`IMMUTABLE` functions** as **global** persisted variables that only privileged users can manipulate. See:

- [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query/13317628#13317628)

**Or** when working with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) as client, use the `\set` or `\gset` meta-commands and [variable substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES).

Comment: The temp table option gave me a lot of trouble. It's an implicit join and needs FROM in an update clause, which made it take minutes to run.

Comment: @Noumenon: Note the added bits about temp tables and autovacuum.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using the [DO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html) instruction to simulate a function. In that way you can declare variables and use them to execute your query!

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html

Comment: I tried, however it always gets a sql error: ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at SQL statement
                                                           DO
$$
DECLARE startDate Timestamp;
BEGIN
 startDate := '2014-4-1';
 select pid from grouping_horizontal where dt = startDate;
END 
$$;

Comment: @Carol: The hint says it all: Use the key word `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`. You cannot `SELECT` without target in a `DO` statement and you cannot return rows ...