# MySQL query Error with IF, END IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a problem in MySQL query with IF, END IF

I made a code like this:

```
SET @columnCnt = 1;
SET @indexCnt = 1;
SET @dataCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`);
WHILE @indexCnt < @dataCnt DO
    IF @indexCnt != @columnCnt THEN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test` WHERE `idx` = @columnCnt) > 0 THEN
                    UPDATE `test` SET `idx` = @indexCnt WHERE `idx` = @columnCnt;
                    @indexCnt = @indexCnt + 1;
            END IF;
    END IF;

    @columnCnt = @columnCnt+1;
END WHILE;
```

And I get Error like this.

```
MySQL Message :
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE @indexCnt < @dataCnt DO
    IF @indexCnt != @columnCnt THEN
            IF ' at line 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where are you executing this? Does this occur inside a function or stored procedure?

Comment: MySQL's flow control statements (if/while) can't be used in a plain client query context - you have to use them in a function or stored procedure.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954095/mysql-declare-while-outside-stored-procedure-how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this;

```
SET @columnCnt = 1
SET @indexCnt = 1
SET @dataCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`)
WHILE (@indexCnt < @dataCnt)
Begin
    IF @indexCnt <> @columnCnt 
    Begin
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test` WHERE `idx` = @columnCnt) > 0 
            Begin
                    UPDATE `test` SET `idx` = @indexCnt WHERE `idx` = @columnCnt
                    SET @indexCnt = @indexCnt + 1;
            End
    End

   SET @columnCnt = @columnCnt+1
End
```