# Using an if statement outside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute this code

```
set @id = 0;
set @the_number = 0;
set @the_message = 0;
set @selected_message = 0;

SELECT id, dest_msisdn, text_message INTO @id, @the_number, @the_message FROM incoming_sms where service_id = 6015592000101762 AND job_status = 0 limit 1;

if(@the_message LIKE '%Bank%')then

select 'h';

end if;
```

but i keep getting an error on

```
if(@the_message LIKE '%Bank%')then

select 'h'' at line 1
```

Why is my if producing an error?.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: The error i am getting is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if(@the_message LIKE '%Bank%')then

select 'h'' at line 1 `

Comment: Have you read the manual about this? What is your purpose?

Answer (score 8):

You need to put your code inside of a strored procedure or function to use the IF statement https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954385/5308054. Here you can see a feature request to fix it https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48777

It is possible to rewrite query without IF statements but I think this question is too to be answered in such way.