# Can not execute query with IF ... THEN statement

Tags: mysql

I can not execute query like: and I dont know why:

```
IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT accountId FROM test_account WHERE content = '123')) THEN
    INSERT INTO test_account (content) VALUES ('123');
END IF;
SELECT accountId FROM test_account WHERE content = '123' LIMIT 1;
```

Error received:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT accountId FROM test_account WHERE content = '123')) THEN INSE' at line 1
```

Edit:

I tried to write procedure first:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTestAccount(var_c VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT accountId FROM test_account WHERE content = var_c)
THEN
    INSERT INTO test_account (content) VALUES (var_c);
END IF;
RETURN (SELECT accountId FROM test_account WHERE content = var_c LIMIT 1);
END;
```

I tried with `THEN` and without...

Can not even query something simple:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getVar(var INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
RETURN var;
END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an if statement outside a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358397/using-an-if-statement-outside-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Thin thread seems to solve a problem that looks like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table/42789261

Comment: Your function code looks fine as is. Did you remember to use `DELIMITER //` (or `$$`, or something other than `;`) before the `CREATE FUNCTION` code? Otherwise MySQL gets confused by the `;`s in the function definition.

Comment: @Nick i'm not sure I know how to use it. will be nice if you sugest anser showing usage.

Comment: @atd_motum I have posted an answer as requested. Can you give it a try and give some feedback thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function code looks fine. I wonder if you forgot to set the delimiter before entering the function to prevent MySQL being confused by the `;`s in the function i.e.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION getTestAccount(var_c VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT accountId FROM test_account WHERE content = var_c) THEN
        INSERT INTO test_account (content) VALUES (var_c);
    END IF;
    RETURN (SELECT accountId FROM test_account WHERE content = var_c LIMIT 1);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 8` got this error

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear the context you are using the code  .. but you could also  try an insert select this way

```
    INSERT INTO test_account (content) 
    SELECT '123' 
    FROM test_account 
    WHERE content = '123' 
    AND   NOT EXISTS(SELECT accountId 
              FROM test_account WHERE content = '123') 
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I wish to create account if content not exists and return accountId