# MySQL Insert with While Loop

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to create a bunch of records in my MySQL database.  This is a one time creation so I am not trying to create a stored procedure.  Here is my code:

```
BEGIN
SET i = 2376921001;
WHILE (i <= 237692200) DO
    INSERT INTO `mytable` (code, active, total) values (i, 1, 1);
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END
```

Here is the error:

> [ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET i = 2376921001
> WHILE (i <= 237692200) DO
> INSERT INTO `coupon` (couponCod' at line 2
> Execution stopped!

I have tried a Declare with the same results.  Code below:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT unsigned DEFAULT 2376921001;
WHILE (i <= 237692200) DO
    INSERT INTO `mytable` (code, active, total) values (i, 1, 1);
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END
```

The one other thing I have tried is with @i instead of just i.  Same error.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the definition of your table ... how is 'code' declared ?

Comment: code is a varchar.  I get the same error when I run this : BEGIN
DECLARE @i VARCHAR unsigned DEFAULT 1001;
WHILE (i <= 2200) DO
    INSERT INTO `coupon` (couponCode, active, totalUses) values (i, 1, 1);
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You cannot use `WHILE` like that; see: [mysql DECLARE WHILE outside stored procedure how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954095/mysql-declare-while-outside-stored-procedure-how)

You have to put your code in a stored procedure. Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 237692001;
    WHILE i <= 237692004 DO
        INSERT INTO mytable (code, active, total) VALUES (i, 1, 1);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f92/1

Alternatively, generate a list of `INSERT` statements using any programming language you like; for a one-time creation, it should be fine. As an example, here's a Bash one-liner:

```
for i in {2376921001..2376921099}; do echo "INSERT INTO mytable (code, active, total) VALUES ($i, 1, 1);"; done
```

By the way, you made a typo in your numbers; 2376921001 has 10 digits, 237692200 only 9.

Comment: Yeah, the numbers were provided and I didn't go in and check them.  Thank you for catching that.  What I am getting from your post is that there is no way to do this with SQL.  That I have to pull the code out and generate each individual statement with PHP.

Comment: @jessier3: You misunderstood; it is perfectly well possible in MySQL. I added sample code and a fiddle to clarify. But feel free to use the alternative approach instead; whatever you find convenient.

Comment: This has been a while ago and I forgot to come back and comment.  This worked.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've got an `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3` with 5.1 ... regarding the documentation this should work :/

Comment: @Megachip Please check your SQL statement with a hex viewer; there may be some invisible Unicode character in there.

Comment: will you please convert the whole process in a single inline sql statement. that will be very helpful.

Comment: How would you insert text in place of numbers? For e.g; first name and last name of 10 persons

Comment: @RajivIyer That is a different scenario. This Q&A is about inserting a range (of numbers), not about inserting a given list of literal values. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 50):

```
drop procedure if exists doWhile;
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE doWhile()   
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 2376921001; 
WHILE (i <= 237692200) DO
    INSERT INTO `mytable` (code, active, total) values (i, 1, 1);
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END;
//  

CALL doWhile();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.