# mysql error on run query

Tags: mysql, database, insert

This is my query in mysql (I use phpmyadmin to execute the query). 
but I can't execute....
can help me please?

```
SELECT count(*) into @cnt FROM `oie_option` WHERE `opt_name` =CONCAT('earning1391',pmonth('2015-09-09')))
if(@cnt <=0)then
INSERT INTO oie_option ('opt_name','opt_value') VALUES (CONCAT('earning1391',pmonth('2015-09-09')),1000);
end if;
```

And this is the error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>
> if(@cnt <=0)then
>       insert into oie_option ('opt_name','opt_value') values(CON' at line 1

Why?
Thanks

Comment: what does pmonth() function do?

Comment: it is myfunction to convert date to persian date

Comment: You can not use if-else etc in the query they are only allowed in stored function, procedures or triggers.

Comment: thanks, exactly i use this query in triger creation.... and return this error

Comment: Get rid off single quotes in the column names `('opt_name','opt_value')` and should be `(opt_name,opt_value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared the variable and corrected.

```
DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
 SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM `oie_option` WHERE `opt_name` = CONCAT( 'earning1391', pmonth (now()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a semicolon in first query.

```
    SELECT count(*) into @cnt FROM `oie_option`
     WHERE `opt_name` =CONCAT('earning1391',pmonth('2015-09-09'));
    if(@cnt <=0)then
    INSERT INTO oie_option ('opt_name','opt_value') VALUES 
     (CONCAT('earning1391',pmonth('2015-09-09')),1000);
     end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to reproduce your situation and this is what I got:

1. You need to put your code inside of a strored procedure or function to use the IF statement https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954385/5308054.
   Here you can see a feature request to fix it https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48777
2. You could avoid using the if statement with query like this

   ```
   INSERT INTO oie_option ('opt_name','opt_value') 
   SELECT CONCAT('earning1391',pmonth('2015-09-09')),1000
   FROM oie_option
   WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM `oie_option` WHERE `opt_name`=CONCAT('earning1391',pmonth('2015-09-09')))=0
   LIMIT 1;
   ```